# Swagger-Web Api Documentation(Bootstrapper is missing in Swashbuckle)

Tags: swagger

I am trying to use swagger for my web api documentation, For that i have installed Swashbuckle from nuget packages but i am unable to get the Bootstrapper package in the swaggerconfig.cs class. so is there any other alternative to get the Bootstrapper package in the swaggerconfig.cs class. Please help me out.  Thank you.

Comment: http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Swashbuckle.Core/4.1.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0/Swashbuckle.Core/Swashbuckle.Core/Bootstrapper.cs?ImageName=Swashbuckle.Core

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your service is hosted in IIS, you can start exposing Swagger docs and a corresponding swagger-ui by simply installing the following Nuget package:

Install-Package Swashbuckle

This will add a reference to Swashbuckle.Core and also install a bootstrapper automatically

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

Thanks.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Most of the tutorial out there use the `Shwashbuckle.Core` package.

Answer (score 2):

If `Swashbuckle.Bootstrapper.Init(config);` is missing. I used an older version of Swashbuckle 4.1.0 it worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have published a tutorial and code [here](https://discventionstech.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/getting-started-with-swashbuckle/) in case you want to have a look

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it by adding reference via `WebApiConfig`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "WebAPI");
        }).EnableSwaggerUi();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with Swashbuckle >= 5.6.0

```
//namespace
using Swashbuckle.Application;

var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API")).EnableSwaggerUi();
```