# Bootstrapper in Swagger - ASP.Net Web API project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, documentation, swagger

I can't find Swashbuckle.Bootstrapper, please see blow:

[image]

Version: Swashbuckle.5.4.0

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430633/swagger-web-api-documentationbootstrapper-is-missing-in-swashbuckle) did not fix my problem. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

You have to inluce Swashbuckle.Application:

```
using Swashbuckle.Application;
```

And bootstrap it using the *extension method* of your `HttpConfiguration`:

```
configuration.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "YourAPI");
}).EnableSwaggerUi();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
I solve it when install Swashbuckle 4.1.0. Try it, i hope it will help.

```
    <package id="Swashbuckle" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```